# Downgrade keyboard back to Jellybean?

Tags: keyboard, 4.3-jelly-bean, gboard

I'm wondering if there is a way to downgrade back to the old 4.3 keyboard.  I use the apostrophe almost every sentence, and now it is gone.  Not the worst thing in the world, but it's ruining my flow.

So is there a way to go back to the 4.3 keyboard (I've not yet gotten 4.4 installed), or is there an app that works the same?

Answer (score 1):

CyanogenMod and other custom ROMs still offer it as part of their ROM packages, and some people have posted the keyboard apk online. This version will not update like Google's keyboard and can be installed on pretty much any ROM. You'll need to enable it **Settings > Language & input**.

- [AOSP Keyboard (4.2.1)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=33502324)
- [AOSP Keyboard w/ number row (4.2.2)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2469303)

Either of these will work and give you back the old layout.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=en).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I just figured it out, after having this complaint myself: Go to Language and Input in settings and turn off Spell Checker.  The keyboard still suggests proper spellings for me, and it inserts apostrophes automatically again.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called Jelly Bean Keyboard by VLLWP but there is a pro version to if you want.